# File read, compare and replace based on comparison in text file

Tags: awk, python, perl

Hi i need guidence to write code for file processing.

i have one file which having ~ as delimeter and each line is keyword is 1st column.

1. First i have to find the lines which matches with ^6999
2. Then go to the $23 filed counted using delimeter ~ and compare it with value 0
3. if compare is true then replace the $24 field with G
4. this to write in same file.

i tried with awk but unable to see any option of writing what to write in python or awk whichever is best for the large file.

```
cat sampletext.dat |grep "^6999"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~"}$23 -gt "0"{$24="G"}1' file.txt

6999~486854~30000000~500000000 ~0~~40844506~0~~0~3830~0~0~ EVELYN          ~242741644~Worldconference~Conference No.~20190104~20190104~7~11108~63.650000~63.65~0~0~~5~2~1~Seconds~11108~11160
~0~0.00~
```

Comment: please provide some sample lines that reflect all possible (`$1==6999 && $23>0` and `$1==6999 && $23==0` and `$1!=6999` ...) .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep`, you can filter the lines with `awk`:

As you don't provide a sample, I cannot test, but something like this should work:

```
awk -F'~' '$1==6999 && $23>0 {$24="G"} {OFS=FS; print}' file.txt
```

To write in the same file:

For `GNU awk`, simply add following option:

```
gawk -i inplace ...
```

Otherwise, you need a temporary file:

```
awk ... > file.txt.tmp && mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

Comment: Hi Plumo,  Thanks for the suggestion . need one more help 
Actual FIle  Below:-
6999~486854~30000000~500000000 ~0~~40844506~0~~0~3830~0~0~ EVELYN          ~242741644~Worldconference~Conference No.~20190104~20190104~7~186~63.650000~63.65~0~0~~5~0~1~Seconds~0~0~0~0.00~
6999~486854~30000000~500000000 ~0~~40844506~0~~0~3830~0~0~ EVELYN          ~~Worldconference~Chairman:~20190104~20190104~7~11108~63.650000~63.65~0~0~~4~2~1~Seconds~11108~11160~0~0.00~

there multiple lines matching with ^6999 ,so i need awk command to update one by one by checking the condition for each line.
Please suggest